# Vue.js project npm install errors

Tags: vue.js, npm

I had multiple errors showing like the following:

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-09-28T23_48_25_332Z-debug.log
```

```
npm WARN old lockfile   errno: -2,
npm WARN old lockfile   code: 'ENOENT',
npm WARN old lockfile   syscall: 'open',
npm WARN old lockfile   path: '/home/./PhpstormProjects/vue-paper-dashboard-master/node_modules/postcss/node_modules/supports-color/package.json
```

I thought it was my internet connection but it turned out not to be like so.
I'm newbie to Vue.js so I was a little bit confused but I found my solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I added these two values to `~/.npmrc`:

```
timeout=60000
prefer-offline=true
```

then I have used the following command with deleting the `node_modules` folder:

```
npm  cache clear --force
```

Then I added `.npmignore` to the root of my project

After that, I used

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

but when I installed it with npm I checked as root like so :

```
sudo  npm update
```

and it worked!